# Cannot Restart Laravel Application After Updating OpenShift Environment Variables

Tags: environment-variables, openshift-online-2

I started up a new [Laravel 5.0 Quick Start at OpenShift](https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-framework-laravel.html). The default laravel home page and auth pages worked just fine.  I changed the OpenShift environment variables as follows:

```
> rhc env set APP_DEBUG=true
> rhc env set APP_ENV=development
```

Note the change to `APP_DEBUG` was inadvertent. I originally only meant to touch `APP_ENV` and then if I understand correctly the OpenShift action hooks should have set other environment variables accordingly. Still I suspect my problem described below would arise whether or not I make that mistake.

In any case after executing the two forgoing commands I can no longer restart. Failing like so:

```
> rhc app restart -a php
Failed to execute action hook 'pre_restart' for {id} application php
Failed to execute action hook 'pre_restart' for {id} application php
```

From the web interface I get this longer message:

```
Setting environment variables...
/usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk: line 154: /var/lib/openshift/{id}//.env/user_vars/APP_ENV: Permission denied


Setting environment variables...
/usr/lib/openshift/cartridge_sdk/bash/sdk: line 154: /var/lib/openshift/{id}//.env/user_vars/APP_ENV: Permission denied
Failed to execute action hook 'pre_restart' for {id} application php
Failed to execute action hook 'pre_restart' for {id} application php
```

I am early enough in setting this up that I could as a last resort start over from scratch.  However I would like to understand the reliable way to change the environment variable from production to development and back.  Also, what permissions are at work here and is there a way to manage them so that the action hooks do not encounter "permission denied?"

Thank you for any help. Please let me know if I can clarify anything.

Comment: I can say for sure that this also happens on a new instance of Laravel 5.0 quick start. I confirmed it could restart out of the box. Ran only the command to set APP_ENV=development. Afterward restart fails as described in the main question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To switch environments simply set the `APPLICATION_ENV` environment variable to `development`. Don't set `APP_DEBUG` and `APP_ENV` directly. Checkout the readme.md file accompanying the QuickStart: https://github.com/luciddreamz/laravel#development-mode

Comment: See also: https://developers.openshift.com/en/php-framework-laravel.html#__development_mode

Comment: @lucidedreamz Thanks. I have tried it that way and encountered the same problem re-starting (see my comment at about the same time you were answering)

But, I have been able to successfully restart if I chmod APP_ENV to 664

I looked at the permissions for **$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR/.env/.user_vars** and noted that before updating **APP_ENV** it is owned by the application-id user. After the update and a restart it is owned by root.

Comment: Ahh! I misread your comment originally.  Got it now.  Thanks!